# Creating dendrograms manually: how to fix "'merge' matrix has invalid contents" in plot.hclust?

Tags: r, hclust

I am creating an `hclust` object manually (i.e. creating a list with the required slots, then changing its class to `hclust`). The merging pattern, heights of bifurcations, ordering of leaf nodes and labels of leaf nodes are known. My goal (and means of testing) is to plot the resulting dendrogram. I am unable to create a plottable `hclust` object with my parameters.

The components of an `hclust` object are described in the `hclust` function documentation 
[here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.1/topics/hclust) (see section **Value**).

The following is a reproducible chunk of `R` code I use to generate and plot my dendrogram.

```
tree <- list()
tree$merge <- matrix(c( -1,  -7,  # row  1
                        -2,  -6,  # row  2
                        -3, -12,  # row  3
                        -4, -14,  # row  4
                        -5,  -8,  # row  5
                        -9, -11,  # row  6
                       -13, -20,  # row  7
                       -15, -19,  # row  8
                         1,   8,  # row  9
                         2,   5,  # row 10
                         3,   6,  # row 11
                         2, -18,  # row 12
                         1,   3,  # row 13
                         2,   4,  # row 14
                       -10,   7,  # row 15
                       -16, -17,  # row 16
                         1,   2,  # row 17
                        15,  16,  # row 18
                         1,  15), # row 19
                     ncol = 2,
                     byrow = TRUE)
tree$height <- c(0.06573653, 0.06573653, 0.06573653, 0.06573653, 0.06573653, 0.06573653, 0.06573653, 0.06573653, 0.11167131, 0.11167131, 0.11167131, 0.12832304, 0.17304035, 0.17304035, 0.17304035, 0.17304035, 0.22965349, 0.22965349, 0.23334799)
tree$labels <- as.character(1:20)
tree$order <- c(1, 7, 15, 19, 3, 12, 9, 11, 2, 6, 5, 8, 18, 4, 14, 13, 20, 10, 16, 17)
class(tree) <- "hclust"
plot(tree)
```

Each row of the `tree$merge` matrix corresponds to a bifurcation. Negative integers refer to the indices of a leaf nodes, whereas positive integers refer to existing clusters by row indices in `tree$merge`.

Running the code results in the following error message.

```
Error in plot.hclust(tree) : 'merge' matrix has invalid contents
```

A sketch of the intended result is pictured below, with the `heights` values marked by additional dotted lines. (The drawing is not to scale.)

[image: Intended dendrogram]

Comment: Just FYI, have a look at the dendextend package for visualizing the dendrogram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The validity of a `hclust` tree is checked by the `.validity.hclust` function. Its source code is given [here](https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/master/src/library/stats/R/hclust.R). Look at lines 121-135.

That you got the error means that your tree is not valid because of its `merge` matrix. It has non-unique elements (e.g., 1 and 2). In a properly constructed `merge` matrix, all entries are unique and run from `-N_obs` to `N_obs-2` (zero excluded), where `N_obs` is a (positive) number of observations. This is checked by the following `if` test in the code:

```
if(identical(sort(as.integer(merge)), c(-(n:1L), +seq_len(n-2L))))
    TRUE
else
    "'merge' matrix has invalid contents"
```

From the reference of `hclust`:

> **merge** an  n − 1  by 2 matrix.
>
> Row  i  of merge describes the merging of clusters at step  i  of the
>   clustering. If an element  j  in the row is negative, then observation
>   − j  was merged at this stage. If  j  is positive then the merge was
>   with the cluster formed at the (earlier) stage  j  of the algorithm.
>   Thus negative entries in merge indicate agglomerations of singletons,
>   and positive entries indicate agglomerations of non-singletons.

All negative entries are singletons (observations), and positive numbers are merges of existing clusters and refer to merging steps of the algorithm.

So, revise your `hclust` object. Here is some code to give you an idea what a proper `hclust` object looks like:

```
iris2 <- iris[1:20,-5]
species_labels <- iris[,5]
d_iris <- dist(iris2)
tree_iris <- hclust(d_iris, method = "complete")
```

Take a closer look at `tree_iris$merge`.

**UPDATE**

After I got more time, I decided to fix your code. I modified the `merge` entry of the `tree`. This is what the working code that reproduces your dendrogram looks like:

```
tree <- list()
tree$merge <- matrix(c( -1,  -7,  # row  1
                        -2,  -6,  # row  2
                        -3, -12,  # row  3
                        -4, -14,  # row  4
                        -5,  -8,  # row  5
                        -9, -11,  # row  6
                        -13, -20,  # row  7
                        -15, -19,  # row  8
                        1,   8,  # row  9: 1,7,15,19
                        2,   5,  # row 10: 2,6,5,8
                        3,   6,  # row 11: 3,12,9,11
                        10, -18,  # row 12: 2,6,5,8 + 18
                        9,   11,  # row 13:  1,7,15,19 + 3,12,9,11
                        12,   4,  # row 14: row 12 + row 4
                        -10,   7,  # row 15: row 7 + 10
                        -16, -17,  # row 16
                        13,   14,  # row 17: row 13 + row 14 
                        15,  16,  # row 18: row 15 + row 16
                        17,  18), # row 19: row 17 + row 18
                     ncol = 2,
                     byrow = TRUE)
tree$height <- c(0.06573653, 0.06573653, 0.06573653, 0.06573653, 0.06573653, 0.06573653, 0.06573653, 0.06573653, 0.11167131, 0.11167131, 0.11167131, 0.12832304, 0.17304035, 0.17304035, 0.17304035, 0.17304035, 0.22965349, 0.22965349, 0.23334799)
tree$labels <- as.character(1:20)
tree$order <- c(1, 7, 15, 19, 3, 12, 9, 11, 2, 6, 5, 8, 18, 4, 14, 13, 20, 10, 16, 17)
class(tree) <- "hclust"
plot(tree)
```

Comment: Much appreciated. To wrap this up for other readers: my mistake was to use some of the positive values in ``tree$merge`` repeatedly ('pointing' to some rows of ``tree$merge`` in multiple instances). This is never needed, however. For instance, suppose I refer to row 1 in row 3 and row 5. Instead, in row 3 I can refer to row 1 and in row I 5 refer to row 3, which represents the already merged branch.